# HP 420i RAID raid level transform

Tags: raid, hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I have HP DL360p Gen8 8 with internal 420i controler and FBWC + battery. ACU says that raid level is 1+0. But in details of the controler i've found:

```
     Mirror Group 0:
        physicaldrive 1I:1:1 (port 1I:box 1:bay 1, SAS, 500 GB, OK)
        physicaldrive 1I:1:2 (port 1I:box 1:bay 2, SAS, 500 GB, OK)
        physicaldrive 1I:1:3 (port 1I:box 1:bay 3, SAS, 500 GB, OK)
     Mirror Group 1:
        physicaldrive 1I:1:4 (port 1I:box 1:bay 4, SAS, 500 GB, OK)
        physicaldrive 2I:1:5 (port 2I:box 1:bay 5, SAS, 500 GB, OK)
        physicaldrive 2I:1:6 (port 2I:box 1:bay 6, SAS, 500 GB, OK)
     Drive Type: Data
```

which is raid 0+1 level. Is there any option to transform this RAID to level 1+0 without data lose? Offline or online - it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reading the `hpacucli` array configuration output incorrectly.

This is displaying two groups of disks, **Mirror Group 0** and **Mirror Group 1**. Each member of each mirror group has a partner in the other mirror group.

Thus:

```
physicaldrive 1I:1:1 pairs to physicaldrive 1I:1:4 
physicaldrive 1I:1:2 pairs to physicaldrive 2I:1:5
physicaldrive 1I:1:3 pairs to physicaldrive 2I:1:6
```

HP Smart Array controllers don't allow or even provide a method of configuring RAID 0+1.

Honestly, I always try to balance drives across SAS SFF-8087 connectors. In this case, that would mean populating bays 1, 2, 3 and 5, 6, 7... That would allow the unlikely failure of a SFF-8087 SAS port or cable such that it would only affect one side of the mirror (or ***Mirror Group***).

Also see: [6 Disk Raid 1+0](https://serverfault.com/questions/381593/6-disk-raid-10/381601#381601)